# Redhat's RHEL8 equivalent of "apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers"

Tags: rhel, redhat-containers, rhel8

I am trying this sample code from "https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted on Python installed on RedHat enterprise linux 7 / 8 image.

Getting error 127 on this line
RUN apk add --no-cache git gcc musl-dev linux-headers

Thanks

Comment: Follow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513731/linux-yum-install-gcc-missing-kernel-headers yum install kernel-headers --disableexcludes=all

Comment: this doesn't refer to airflow, I think, so could you remove the airflow tag please?

Answer (score 0):

On Red Hat Enterprise Linux, installing the `gcc` package installs both the system C compiler and the C library development files, including the required UAPI kernel headers. So this command is sufficient to install a C development environment:

```
yum install gcc
```

If you need the C++ compiler, you should use this instead:

```
yum install gcc-c++
```